# How to support hive script on mesos

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, mesos

We are moving from YARN to Mesos. Currently, users are using Hive scripts to process their data. 
Is there any way to migrate these scripts to Mesos without change or with small changes?
Hive on Spark may be an solution, but Hive on Spark seems only for Yarn.